# Wall drain too high for p trap

Tags: plumbing, drain, p-trap

Appears my wall drain is set too high to meet my p trap. I assume I will need to decrease the vanity sink drain some but either way the current p trap would land on the sink drain tightening nut.

I was wondering if I could attach a longer down piece coming out of the wall before the p trap bend; or will that cause drain issues???

Is flex hose an option here?

[image: under sink showing bowl, tail piece & p-trap]
<sup>click to embiggen</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As noted in a comment, I would suggest looking for a shorter tail piece without the fancy, tall nut (which, I'm sure, works very nicely for hand-tightening).

Normally the nut would be less than an inch tall, and it appears that a very short tail piece with a normal size nut would give you all the room you need to mate the two pieces up without ripping into the wall.

The standard size nut might not be *quite* as easy to tighten by hand (as is recommended for these plastic nuts), but it'll be worth the (very minor) struggle to actually be able to use the sink.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open the wall and set the wall stub out at the proper level, patched the drywall, and mudded/sanded/painted to meet code.

You can't flex hose and a trap deeper than 4" can allow the trap to siphon.

https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/deep-traps_o